# To prove Riemann surface isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be Riemann surfaces.
If we want to prove $f$:$A$→$B$ is isomorphism of Riemann surfaces, what we should do?

My book reads like this,

①Computing $f$'s effect on the cotangent spaces of $A$ and $B$
②To show $f$ is local analytic isomorphism ( I don't know it's definition).
③To show $f$ is bijective, then, we can conclude that $f$ is global isomorphism.

My question : What is the definition of local analytic isomorphism?
And why we can say $f$ is global isomorphism if we could show $f$ is also bijective?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a Riemann surface?

Comment: $\log$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb{C}^*$ to $\Bbb{C/2i\pi Z}$. For less "trivial" examples you need to look at the isomorphism $\Bbb{C/(Z+iZ)}$ to $E:y^2=4x^3-g_2(i) x$ (plus its point at $\infty$) given by $z\to (\wp_i(z),\wp_i'(z))$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher  I know , 1-dimmensional connected complex manifold.